# Issue with zend 2 log

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-log

I am currently working with zend 2 logger. I have a table `error_log` with the following fields:

- error_log_id
- message
- timestamp
- priorityName
- priority
- ip
- user_id

And the following is my code

```
$db         = $this->service->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$uId        = 0;

if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
    $oId        = $auth->getIdentity();
    $uId        = $oId->user_id;
}

$mapping = array(
    'timestamp'     => 'timestamp',
    'priority'      => 'priority',
    'priorityName'  => 'priorityName',
    'message'       => 'message',
);
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Db($db, 'error_log_table', $mapping);
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);

$logger->info('Informational message');
```

This works fine and the following fields will be updated. timestamp, priority, priorityName, & message.

I also want to update the user_id and ip field. How can i do this? (In zend 1, we can do this by using `setEventItem()` function). What function I have to call to add extra parameter in zend 2 log?

Somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use $logger->info() with a second parameter "extra". This should be a Traversal, e.g. an array.

Have a try with the following.

```
$logger->info('message', array('user_id' => $uId, 'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```

I guess you have to add an additional database column "extra", where the extra logging event data is stored in.

Comment: I use the above code and I added the following code too.. `$mapping = array( 'timestamp' => 'timestamp', 'priority' => 'priority', 'priorityName' => 'priorityName', 'message' => 'message', 'extra' => array('user_id'=> 'user_id', 'ip'=>'ip') ); $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Db($db, 'error_log_table', $mapping);` Now it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Briefly: declare own logger with dependency from `AuthenticationService`, override `log` method, use `$extra` variable to store additional data

In detail:

**Application\Log\LoggerFactory.php**

```
class LoggerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    protected $mapping = array(
        // Your mapping here
    );

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $authenticationService = $serviceLocator->get('Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService');

        $dbAdapter = $serviceLocator->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\StatisticAdapter');
        $writer = new DbWriter($dbAdapter, 'error_log_table', $this->mapping);

        $logger = new Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $logger->setAuthenticationService($authenticationService);

        return $logger;
    }

}
```

**Application\Log\Logger.php**

```
class Logger extends \Zend\Log\Logger
{

    protected $authenticationService;

    public function setAuthenticationService($authenticationService)
    {
         $this->authenticationService = $authenticationService;
    }

    public function log($priority, $message, $extra = array())
    {

        $remoteAddress = new RemoteAddress;
        $ip = $remoteAddress->setUseProxy(true)->getIpAddress();   

        $userId = null;
        if ($this->authenticationService->hasIdentity()) {
             $userId = $this->authenticationService->getIdentity()->getId();
        } 

        $extra = array_merge($extra, array(
            'ip' => ip2long($ip),
            'user_id' => $userId
        ));

        return parent::log($priority, $message, $extra);
    }
```

**module.config.php**

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Zend\Log' => 'Application\Log\LoggerFactory',
    ),
```

**Your controller**

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Log')->info('Info');
```